# How convert an undirected graph to a directed graph in which each node has at most K parents?

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I need to convert an undirected graph to a DAG that requires each node have at most K parents. I want to minimize the number of edges lost in the conversion. Can anyone suggest some methods?

Comment: So you mean that each edge of the initial graph is transformed to one of the two possible directed edges ? Do you have any example ? To evaluate the size and the density of the initial graph.

Comment: No. I need to assign a direction to each edge. Suppose the undirected graph is sparse and has O(N) nodes, and O(N) edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so assuming that I understood the problem, a nice algorithm to solve this is Kuhn-Munkres (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

For each edge, you want to associate one of the two nodes (the one it is directed to).
For each node, you have maximum K association possible.

So your bigraph is on one side (let s say left side) the edges of your initial graph and on the other (let s say right side) K times each nodes + one sink node per edge. The sink nodes correspond to the loss of the edge.

Then you put the edges in your bigraph (not to be confused with the edges of your problem). You put a 0 cost edge, for all the connections of your initial graph and a 1 cost edge from any left node to its sink node.

Then you use Kuhn-Munkres algorithm to minimize the association.